Best way to accurately model the complex network of concrete runways/taxiways/roads/paths of an airfield in Unreal?
I can understand the concept of creating a network of basic roads using splines but imagine a large area of concrete with lots of complex curves, shapes and transitions to model like an airfield. The area of concrete could extend to over a mile. What would be the best way to model this please? I’m looking for proper mesh modelling here - not an applied texture. Is there any problem using a vast mesh or would you break it down into smaller sections which you then place together? I would need to be able to view the paths and runways stretching out into the far distance so a LOD based system wouldn’t work so well. I’d also need vehicles to be able to operate realistically on the surface, following any contours I build into the mesh. Am I asking the impossible!? Thanks!

friend!
First of all, there's actually a handful of questions there, so I will try to answer each one specifically.
Let me start by saying this:

[...] model the complex network of concrete runways/taxiways/roads/paths of an airfield in Unreal?

model and Unreal. Those two words should never be put in the same sentence.
Although current UE Modelling tool is pretty useful, it is far from what a dedicated software such as Blender or Maya is capable of.
And judging by the complexity of what you are making, maybe you should consider that possibility.
Now, to you second question:

Is there any problem using a vast mesh or would you break it down into
smaller sections which you then place together?

Separate one "thing" into different "things" in Unreal only if you have to.
If not, don't do it.
If you have any gameplay features in mind that require that small "nodes" of your map to each be a different Actor, that's one thing.
But separating all parts of your map into tiny ones just because... You can? No. Don't do it.
Here's how I would start this:
I would block the whole thing in Blender, import all at once and use its own mesh as the complex collision and set the Mesh to use its complex collision as simple.
If there's any impact on performance by doing that, only then I would start to work my way down, you know?
"Okay, this can`t be one giant piece. How about like 5 smaller ones?"
You see?
What I mean by this is that, although is very positive to keep possible bottlenecks in mind, don't spend time fixing problems that you don't have, you know?

I would need to be able to view the paths and runways stretching out into the far distance so a LOD based system wouldn’t work so well

I don't understand your basis for this.
Having access to LOD doesn't mean you have to use in a way that doesn't generate what you want, nor that you need to use it at all.
In the Static Mesh Editor you can just disable it, but be aware. Doing this can have a very significant impact on your performance.

I’d also need vehicles to be able to operate realistically on the surface, following any contours I build into the mesh. Am I asking the impossible!? Thanks!

If that's possible?
Yes. All you need is to use AI. Blackboard can help you a lot with this.
Phew! I think that was it.
Anyway, hope I helped you, friend!

Thanks for your advice Ronaldo, much appreciated. I'm recreating an airfield and surrounding area and Unreal ticks a lot of boxes in terms of realistic lighting & large world area, not to mention the nanite tech which will help no end with the immense detail required. I'll take your advice and try to create the whole system of roads, taxiways and runways as one large static mesh and see how I go with that.  Mesh will be 2km x 2km so hopefully it will render into the far distance without major performance issues.  It will certainly make everything much simpler if kept as one object.  Thanks!

"But separating all parts of your map into tiny ones just because... You can? No. Don't do it." In fact, we do that because it's more manageable and versatile for developers and modellers and allows game engines to perform occlusion culling and GPUs to work more efficiently memory-wise.

Thank you for sharing that knowledge!
But wouldn't you agree that, the case you describe, is an actual reason to do it that way? I don't know if I expressed myself well, but my point isn't that there are no reasons to do it. My point is to don't do it if you don't have a reason.
I mean, I totally agree with your point, but wouldn't you also agree that, depending on the type of project you are working on, that concern you brought wouldn't be an issue?
That's my point, you see? It depends. Do you have a reason for it? Do it. If not, don't.
